# How to find approximate solution to equation？

Tags: python, pandas, sympy

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows, the first row is listed here:
[image]
Here is an equation：
[image]
FV_dirty in the equation is 'closing_price',
C_i = C = coupon_rate * face_value * Interest_payment_interval ,
n = Interest_payment_time,
t(T(0), T_I(i)) is an integer multiple of Interest_payment_interval, when i = 1, t(T(0), T_I(1)) = Interest_payment_interval * 1.
r_i = rf_i + zspread , the value of rf_i is a numerically named column in the dataframe.
zspread is a constant
I want to calculate zspread for each row.
Here is some data：

```
closing_price:107.7301
coupon_rate:4.39 
Interest_payment_time:8
Interest_payment_interval:1
face_value:100
0:0.01342
1:0.021977
2:0.022843
3:0.023907
4:0.02465
5:0.025296
6:0.026264
7：0.0268
8：0.026793
```

My code is as follows：

```
import sympy
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('...')
def zspread_solution(df):
    FV = df['closing_price']
    COUPON_RATE = df['coupon_rate']
    T = df['Interest_payment_interval']
    N = df['face_value']
    C = COUPON_RATE * T * N
    z = sympy.Symbol('z')
    fun = - FV
    for item_index in range(int(df['Interest_payment_time'] + 1)):
        if item_index != df['Interest_payment_time']:
            DELTA_T = (item_index + 1) * T
            rate = df[item_index + 1] + z
            NUMERATOR = (1 + rate)**DELTA_T
            item = C/NUMERATOR
            fun += item
        else:
            DELTA_T = item_index * T
            rate = df[item_index] + z
            NUMERATOR = (1 + rate)**DELTA_T
            item = N/NUMERATOR
            fun += item
    Z = sympy.solve(fun, z)
    return Z
```

I want to use the sympy.solve function in sympy to calculate zspread, for this I constructed an equation fun.But the fun function I get is as follows:
[image]
It differs from the equation expression from the second term, when the exponent power is 2.Moreover, zspread cannot be calculated using sympy.solve.
What's wrong with the code? How can I calculate zspread?

Comment: It looks like youre dealing with a problem that should be solved numerically, not analytically.

Comment: Sympy finds analytical solutions, they are exact but often hard to interpret or use, and often cannot be found at all. Numerical libraries such as scipy will give you approximate solutions.